# OS call gives permission denied

Tags: python, bash, user-interface, tkinter

Hey I am trying to make a GUI based application which can be used to enumerate a pcap file, desired functionality is simply when the user clicks on enumerate, another window comes up and user can enter the file name that's supposed to be run.

Just for the sake of testing I am currently taking input in raw bash commands but unfortunately that's not working for me.

Below is my code :-

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import subprocess
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.minsize(300,300)
#back = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Extractor")
e1 = Entry(window)

def disp():
        subprocess.call([e1.get()])
def callback():
        Label(window,text="Command").grid(row=0)
        e1 = Entry(window)
        e1.insert(10,"Please input")
        e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
        process = tkinter.Button(window,text="GO",command=disp)
        process.grid(row=10,column=5)

toplabel=tkinter.Label(window,text="Enumeration tool for PCAP")


enum = tkinter.Button(window,text ="Enumerate",command=callback)
enum.grid(row=10)
window.mainloop()
```

The error generated :-

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1544, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "GUI.py", line 11, in disp
    subprocess.call([e1.get()])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I need help with calling that another window in another window-frame, then how can I put some commands like `bash <input>` such that bash is always hidden and only input executes the script & how can I fix that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work with very minimal changes:

```
...

window.title("Extractor")
e1 = None # <- your were creating two instances of your entry, one in 
          # global namespace and other local to the functions. Why?

def disp():
        subprocess.call([e1.get()]) # no need for for global, its a read op
def callback():
        global e1 # refer to global e1 on writes
        Label(window,text="Command").grid(row=0)
        e1 = Entry(window)

...
```

You can create other windows besides the `Tk()` root window, calling `tkinter.Toplevel(root)` which instantiates a new root child window.